# How can you stop an app from refreshing if it enters the background?

Tags: ios, swift, background

I'm building a social network with the usual functions like a feed. When I am closing the app via home button it sometimes just needs a minute to get refreshed when I am re-entering the app.

Obviously that is bad, when you are scrolling down the feed, you want to get back to the spot where you were the last time. It even refreshes the "new Post" screen when I wrote the title and go to safari to copy a link.. You get the gist of the problem.
Apps like Reddit do it very well and quite long.

Research just showed me functions to fetch in the background, which will let the app stay in its current state, I suppose, but I don't want to fetch anything, just expand the time before it refreshes.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

   UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval( 60 ) )
}
```

...

Any help to get a longer "active" state is appreciated, I'm just clueless!
Thank You

Comment: Can't you save the last post you saw when you entered background state, and you go to the app to scroll to this post?

Comment: Hey Tal, it seems unnecessary complex when I look at apps like Reddit who just stay in its current state instead of loading all of the UI and data again. And when I open the app after a longer time, like a day later, I would like the app to be refreshed completely, you know?

Comment: Well, some things are more complex than they look :) afaik you can't make the app active when it's in the background. you can start a timer and measure how long the user has been in the background and refresh the app completely if it reaches your threshold. Anyway, the app will kill itself after a certain amount of time. you can't keep it "inactive" for too long.

Comment: But then again there are some apps who do it, without reloading. And the time before it reloads vary from literally seconds to minutes, so I thought there should be some mechanism behind it. Just wanted to check if somebody knows something.

Comment: Agree w/@TalCohen.  iOS can terminate your backgrounded app pretty much at will. You should however make sure you free shared resources like the camera, etc. or it will be terminated every time. I'd look at Apple's docs on [preparing for backgrounding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background) for that and other tips.

Comment: Hmm, well than it will remain a mystery for now :) Anyways, thanks for your time Tal and Mark!

Comment: @Malte recent ios versions had problems with multitasking, just wait for a new release, I think it shouldn't happen that frequently and only when os needs free RAM space it might remove your app from the stack. You don't have to do anything, this is something which Apple should fix.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , usually it happens when we are on the last index we call the refresh api with loader and wait for response and append in previous response . index will be maintained

Second if you want to refresh when appbecomeActive from background state you make app the all the list refresh and index won't be maintained 
or 
when app enter backgroundstate get the index number and when app is inthe foreground or active state just scroll to that index

if my anwswer is according to your question please elaborate your question

Thank you

Comment: Hey Hassan, I don't really understand your first point. And the second could work but isn't exactly what I want because of all the reloading of the UI and data that is fetched after the start.